# SQL Server Kafka connector re-inserting records when taking snapshot

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have a SQL table **BILLS**, and it is setup in a way that whenever a stored procedure runs, a new row will be added into **BILLS**, and there should not be any UPDATE / DELETE.

Now coming to the SQL Server connector part, ideally, I want only these newly inserted rows to be pushed to a Kafka topic. And once we have the CDC enabled for the SQL table, the new data is indeed showing up, so far so good.

However, aside from all these new data, occasionally there is also snapshot data that are inserted as part of the connector snapshotting process, this causes duplication of data in the Kafka topic. This issue can be easily replicated when the connector service was restarted, and all the existing data from the SQL table will be again being pushed into the Kafka topic.

In the documentation it is stated that

> If the connector stops for any reason (including communication failures, network problems, or crashes), after a restart the connector resumes reading the SQL Server CDC tables from the last point that it read.

So, my assumption is that there should not be any duplication of data in the Kafka topic. Is this an expected behavior?

**Connector version:** Debezium SQL Server 1.5.4

```
"snapshot.mode": "initial",
"snapshot.new.tables": "parallel",
"connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Last point it reads" doesn't mean there won't be duplication. For example, if that "point" failed to be persisted, it'll have to re-read any data from the "older point"